# Increment adding new row

Tags: jquery

How can I increment my new row to continue on from the existing numbers?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QYGpe/2/)

```
$('.add-button').click( function() {
//var $current_num = $("table#myTable tbody tr td").length;
    var $this = $("table#myTable tbody tr");
    var $current_num = $this.find("td:first").attr("rowspan").length;
    var $incremented = $this.find('td.increment').val(parseInt($this.find('td.increment').val())+1);

     $("#myTable tbody").append("<tr><td rowspan='2'>" + $incremented + "</td><td>other data</td><td>even more data</td></tr><tr><td colspan='8'>test</td></tr>");
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Table cells don't have `.val()` function attached to them, only form elements do. For accessing/setting DOM element's "values" use `.html()` or `.text()`

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the increment value as follows and it should work:

```
var $this = $("table#myTable tbody");
var $incremented = $this.find('td[rowspan]:last').text()*1 + 1;
```

Updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QYGpe/16/

Answer (score 0):

Give a css class name (`increment`)to your **TD**s which shows the counter number and use `last()` method to get the last TD which shows the last counter number, and get the content of that and increment and then add it in the new row.

```
$(function(){
   $('.add-button').click( function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $("table#myTable tbody tr");
    var $current_num = $this.find("td:first").attr("rowspan").length;
    var $incremented =parseInt($("#myTable").find('td.increment').last()
                                                                     .html())+1;

     $("#myTable tbody").append("<tr><td rowspan='2'  class='increment'>" + 
               $incremented + "</td><td>other data</td>
               <td>even more data</td></tr><tr><td colspan='8'>test</td></tr>");

   });
 });
```

Working sample http://jsfiddle.net/QYGpe/14/

Answer (score 0):

```
var length = $this.length;

var $incremented = (length/2)+1;
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

use `.text()` instead of `.val()` for `<td>` element

```
$(function() {
    var $tbody = $("#myTable tbody");
    $('.add-button').click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var lastId = parseInt($tbody.find("td[rowspan]:last").text()) + 1;
        $tbody.append("<tr><td rowspan='2'>" + lastId + "</td><td>other data</td><td>even more data</td></tr><tr><td colspan='8'>test</td></tr>");
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/QYGpe/17/)